# Prevent assignment of non-existent field in ctypes Structure

Tags: python, ctypes

It's relatively easy to shoot yourself in the foot with a typo when assigning a field in a ctypes structure:

```py
structure.fieeld = 10  # Everything works fine except structure.field is unchanged...
```

Is there anyway to turn this into a exception?  The usual `__setattr__` tricks don't seem to work with the innards of `ctypes.Structure`

Comment: Adding `__slots__ = []` to your structure definition will cause assignment to nonexistent fields to become an error.

Comment: @jasonharper At least setting `__slots__` to a list of valid members (like ctypesgen does) is not able to prevent setting nonexistent fields. Is that different with an empty list? If so, why?

Comment: @jasonharper I just checked. Setting empty `__slots__` also does not prevent nonexistent fields for me, as of python 3.11.

Comment: It works for me, on 3.11.2.  Do you have something going on beyond the basic use of `Structure`?  Multiple levels of inheritance, perhaps - if that's the case, you need `__slots__` at each level to make sure there's no `__dict__` attribute that can hold not-previously-defined attributes.

Comment: @jasonharper I figured out the problem, the definition of slots must be in the class body. ctypesgen uses an empty class definition and sets slots afterwards using classname.__slots__ = ..., in which case there probably still is a `__dict__` attribute. Thanks!